# For invertible $A$ show that $\lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| x-y \|_A < r \rbrace= \lbrace x + A^{-1} y: y \in B_r(0) \rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

I am struggling with the following

> **Problem**: Let $| \cdot|$ be the Euclidian Norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ Matrix. Define $\|x\|_A = |Ax|$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Let $B_r^A(x) = \lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| x -y \|_A < r \rbrace$ be the open ball in the $\| \cdot \|_A$ norm. Show that: $$ B_r^A(x) = \lbrace x + A^{-1}y: y \in B_r(0) \rbrace$$

**My approach**: When I read about that problem I immediately thought of the theorem about the general solution to a system of linear equations which contains of a particular solution to $Ax=b$ and Kernel of $A$. I cannot tell though if they are related.

However I wanted to show both inclusions for this exercise, but I have a feeling that I am too weakly equipped to work with norms yet, although I know **Youngs**- and **Hölders**-Inequalities.

"$\subset$": Let $y \in B_r^A(x) \implies \|x-y\|_A < \iff |A(x-y)|<r \iff |Ax-Ay|<r$
I suppose I need to show that $y \in B_r(0) \iff |y| <r$ but I don't see how the inverse of the Matrix $A^{-1}$ comes into play.

"$\supset$": Let $z \in \lbrace x + A^{-1}y: y \in B_r(0) \rbrace \implies \exists y \in B_r(0): z= x + A^{-1}y$ and I want to show that $z \in B_r^A(x)$ that is $|A(x-z)|<r$

$$|A(x-z)|=|A(x-(x+A^{-1}y)|=|Ax-Ax-AA^{-1}y|=|y|<r$$
because $y \in B_r(0)$ so this would make sense to  me. I therefore would like some insight with "$\subset$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but I think the notation somewhat confusing due to $y$ showing up in two places where it is not the same. Given $y \in B_r^A(x)$, what you want to show is that there is some $y' \in B_r(0)$ so that $y = x + A^{-1}y'$, hence showing $y \in \{x + A^{-1}y' : y' \in B_r(0)\}$ and giving $\subset$.

Working backwards by multiplying both sides of $y = x + A^{-1}y'$ by $A$ and rearranging, we get $y' = Ay - Ax$ as the likely candidate. We must check that $|y'| <r$ to see that $y' \in B_r(0)$, but this follows because
$$
|y'| = |Ay - Ax| = |Ax - Ay| = \|x-y\|_A< r.
$$

Comment: Dammit,beat me to it again,almost had it.Good answer,grumble,grumble.....lol

Comment: I hate it when that happens, haha.

Comment: Actually,I was going to begin with the OP's beginning containment and $\|Ax-Ay\| < r$, denote the other y by y' and use the reverse triangle inequality to directly derive $x+A^{-1}y$. That probably would have worked,but it would have been much more complicated.